# Escape \n\t\t in the json output

Tags: json

How to remove new \n\t\t  from below json code

```
{"total_target":"100","campaign_details":" \n\t\t<p><u><h4>Basic Information<\/h4><\/u><\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Campaign Name<\/b>  :   1034 SAP HANA<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Client Code<\/b>  :   1034<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Campaign Type<\/b>  :   Whitepaper<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Account Manager<\/b>  :   Super Admin<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Campaign Mode <\/b>  :   Email<\/p>\n\t\t<hr>\n\t\t\n\t\t<p><u><h4>Geographical Location<\/h4><\/u><\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Country<\/b>  :   India,Canada<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>State<\/b>  :   delhi,MAHARASHTRA<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>City <\/b>  :   <\/p>\n\t\t<hr>\n\t\t<p><u><h4>Job Specification<\/h4><\/u><\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Job Title<\/b>  :   IT Manager, VP, MD<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Job Level<\/b>  :   V-Level,C-Level<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Job Function <\/b>  :   <\/p>\n\t   "}
        get_lead:1019   {"total_target":"100","campaign_details":" \n\t\t<p><u><h4>Basic Information<\/h4><\/u><\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Campaign Name<\/b>  :   1034 SAP HANA<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Client Code<\/b>  :   1034<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Campaign Type<\/b>  :   Whitepaper<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Account Manager<\/b>  :   Super Admin<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Campaign Mode <\/b>  :   Email<\/p>\n\t\t<hr>\n\t\t\n\t\t<p><u><h4>Geographical Location<\/h4><\/u><\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Country<\/b>  :   India,Canada<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>State<\/b>  :   delhi,MAHARASHTRA<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>City <\/b>  :   <\/p>\n\t\t<hr>\n\t\t<p><u><h4>Job Specification<\/h4><\/u><\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Job Title<\/b>  :   IT Manager, VP, MD<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Job Level<\/b>  :   V-Level,C-Level<\/p>\n\t\t<p><b>Job Function <\/b>  :   <\/p>\n\t   "}
```

Comment: If you tell us which programming language you are using (or plan to use), someone will certainly be able to assist. By the way, I would add to the tags the language as well.

Comment: i am using jquery ajax

Comment: No, you are using JavaScript. @wroniasty gave you the solution below.

Comment: By the way, it would be interesting to know where these escape chars are coming form... Perhaps, you can prevent their insertion altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Like this (in JavaScript):

```
var filteredJsonString = stringWithJson.replace(/\n|\t/g, '')
```